# how to convert null coefficients for the variables in equations "x^2+x^2+2x-x-25" to be "+1x^2+1x^2+2x-1x-25"?

Tags: java, string, math, equations, coefficients

This is my attempting to fix the coefficient of any math equation variable 
for sum coefficients of the same variables   like "x^2+x^2+2x-x-25" to be "+1x^2+1x^2+2x-1x-25" and then make the summation to be "2x^2+x-25", Notice that i have done the summation process in another method.

```
private static String fixCoeff(String equ)
{
    equ=equ.toLowerCase();//change equation variables to lower case
    equ=equ.trim();//remove white spaces
    String []characters={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
    int index=-1;
    String fixedCoeff="";
    for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++)
    {
        if(!equ.contains(characters[i]))
        {
            continue;
        }
        //if a not found in equ i++ 
        //if true execute this
        while(equ.indexOf(characters[i],++index)!=-1)
        {


            index=equ.indexOf(characters[i]);
            if(index==0)
            {
                fixedCoeff+="+1"+equ;
                equ=fixedCoeff;
                index=2;
                break;

            }
            else
            {

                if (equ.charAt(index-1)=='+'||equ.charAt(index-1)=='-')
                {
                    fixedCoeff=equ.substring(-1,index-1);
                    fixedCoeff+="1"+equ.substring(index-1,equ.length()-1);
                    equ=fixedCoeff;
                    index++;
                    break;
                }

            }

        //  if (index==equ.length()-1) {//if we found last element in equ is a variable
                //break;
            //}
        }//end while

    }//end for loop 


    return equ;

}//end fixCoeff
```

**input cases :**

1. a
2. x
3. x^2
4. x^2+x^2

**output cases :**

1. +1a
2. +1x
3. +1x^2
4. +1x^2+1x^2

Comment: What does your code output? It's easier to answer your question if you tell us what's happening.

Comment: @user1854282 check out my answer it accomplishes what you want with fewer lines of code.

Comment: @user1854282 isn't output case 4 wrong? shouldn't it be +1x^2 + 1x^2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just to add up to @brso05 answer,

it is another way of doing this:

```
    String s ="x^2+x^2+2x-x-25";
    s=s.replaceAll("(?<!\\d)([a-z])", "1$1");    // <-- replaces any lower letters with 1 concatanted with the same letter
    if(!s.startsWith("-")){
        s="+"+s;  //<-- if the first character is not negative add a + to it.
    }
    System.out.println(s);
```

**output:**

```
+1x^2+1x^2+2x-1x-25
```

Comment: nice no loop! I like it

Answer (score 1):

You can do this much easier using `String.replaceAll()` like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++)
{
    if(!equ.contains(characters[i]))
    {
        continue;
    }
    equ = equ.replaceAll(("(?<!\\d)" + characters[i]), ("1" + characters[i]));
}
if(!equ.startsWith("-") && !equ.startsWith("+"))
{
    equ = "+" + equ;
}
```

This will replace the character where there is no digit in front of it with 1x(or whatever the current character is).  This uses regex with a negative lookbehind to make sure there are no digits in front of the character then it will replace with 1(character).

Here is a self-contained example:

```
String line = "x-x^2+3x^3";
line = line.replaceAll("(?<!\\d)x", "1x");
System.out.println("" + line);
```

This will output `1x-1x^2+3x^3`.